# how to start mailman server in test mode

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed mailman server locally(localhost:3000) and run the mailman server using

`bundle exec script/mailman_server start`.

it access my local 'development' database. But I want to access my 'test' database. Is there any way to do this?? any help would be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI has an environments options so you'd just run:

```
bundle exec script/mailman_server start --environment=test
```